# How does "Concealment" transfer to Dedicated Transports?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have been looking over the combat benefits from the various force organisations granted by [**Gladius Strike Forces**](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-iowHz2Qm6pA/VX42BoIEkJI/AAAAAAAAGpU/3Cp1oP5-yBg/s1600/1.JPG). The one that interests me is the 10th Company bonus where all units in this Company gain Concealment (Stealth until almost anything other than embarking, disembarking or shooting). However, I have a number of land speeder storms that act as dedicated transports that gain this status as well. So my question is **if I disembark a concealed unit and its transport moves, does the entire unit loose concealment or just the Transport?**

Comment: I'm going to check this in greater detail, but from the wording it looks like the unit and the transport both lose Concealment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disembarkation is a move. So getting out will make the unit lose stealth, though the transport would retain stealth as long as it didn't move. If the transport moves (before or after disembarking) it loses stealth as well.

Answer (score 1):

The 10th Company's special rule Concealed Positions gives Stealth to *each unit in the formation* that deploys using the Infiltration rule.  We also know that the Dedicated Transport is a separate unit from the unit that disembarked.

> Dedicated Transports do not use up any slots on a Force Organisation
>   Chart, but otherwise function as separate units.

Therefore, if the transport moves, **only** the Dedicated Transport will lose Stealth. Each unit--independently--will have special rule Stealth until it performs an action that cancels it.